# How to unlock Mac OS 9.x user account OR install Ubuntu on this iMac

Tags: linux, passwords, user-accounts, mac-os-classic

I have an old CRT iMac that I found on the street. It has a CD-ROM drive.

I accidentally locked myself out of the user accounts while playing with it. (I typed in a password quickly and coudn't retype it exactly the same way...)

Is there any way to install Linux on it, or to unlock the user account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot off an installation CD (hold the 'C' down during startup) and you'll have options to reset the password.

Comment: Where can I get said install CD?

Comment: Well, I can't send you mine, because I might need it!  On a whim I prowled around and found one http://bit.ly/6JdrnX

Comment: Can you send ISO? We both have legal use of the system, I just don't have it on media now...

Answer (score 1):

If you go with Linux (which I would certainly recommend):

First of all, Ubuntu will not work very well on a computer that old. You should try Fluxbuntu or some other lightweight version of Ubuntu (I wouldn't recommend Xubuntu though, it is not lightweight enough).

The live install disk should just detect and use the mac hardware, though I don't have experience with this myself and it really depends on how old the computer is. From there on it should work just like on any other hardware.

Comment: Does these lightweight "ubuntus" come in CD (not DVD) versions?

Comment: Yes, most *ubuntu systems will come in an ISO small enough to put on a CD. I went and looked at the fluxbuntu website, and it turns out they are based on an Ubuntu version from 2 years ago. I would say that you should try Xubuntu, since it is the lightest thing that is based on ubuntu and is reasonably recent. Of course, you should really do your homework and see which Linux will work best on older mac hardware, as Ubuntu might not really be the best thing in this case...